# Android Fragment. Проблема с заменой фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

в приложении есть ViewPager c фрагментами и в каждом из них есть список RecyclerView. при нажатии на каждый item списка создается новый фрагмент методом replace().
Проблема: созданный фрагмент располагается по верх всего(как и задумывалось), но его задний фон всё равно работает, т.е. ViewPager с фрагмента( в которых RecyclerView + OnClickListener)

activity_start.xml

```
public class ProductDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public ProductDetailFragment() {
    }
    public static ProductDetailFragment newInstance(Product product){
        ProductDetailFragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name",product.getName());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
     
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Мой OnCreate в MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabs.setTabMode(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);// Make TabLayout scrollable
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    //toggle.getToolbarNavigationClickListener().onClick();
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Мой RecyclerView Adapter + OnClickListener

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductDataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Product product = products.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(product.getImage());
    holder.nameView.setText(product.getName());
    holder.priceView.setText("$ "+product.getPrice());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("myLog",position+"");
            ProductDetailFragment datail = ProductDetailFragment.newInstance(product);
            transaction = ((FragmentActivity)v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, datail);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Класс фрагмента, который я хочу поместить

```
public class ProductDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public ProductDetailFragment() {
    }
    public static ProductDetailFragment newInstance(Product product){
        ProductDetailFragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name",product.getName());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
     
        return view;
    }
}
```

Не хочется создавать вместо фрагмента отдельную активити.
Надеюсь, что так можно как-то выкрутиться.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Просто сделайте у верхнего фрагмента непрозрачный background вот и все

Comment: так background будет, но проблема не решается. всё по прежнему "тыкается" и "свайпается".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам советовал в функции `onCreateView()` в фрагменте который вы хотите показать устанавливать ему полноэкранное отображение так:

```
getActivity(). getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

либо так:

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

но любой из этих флагов будет работать пока активность жива, поэтому вам нужно сначала обнулять значения а потом устанавливать:

```
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#summary) по "флагам" которые есть вообще, из них можно выбрать которые вам будут подходить лучше всего. Так же можно использовать `dialogFragment` и там установить стиль для полноэкранного отображения. Удачи :)